# Dictionary comprehension from random word (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

How can I express this using dictionary comprehension in python? Is it even possible?
Thank you.

```
#word = "anyword\n"
k, word_dict = 0, {}
for letter in word[:-1]:
    word_dict[k] = letter
    k += 1
```

Comment: Why not `dict(enumerate(word[:-1]))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`word_dict = {i: word[i] for i in range(len(word) - 1)}`

This iterates over all indexes but last of `word` and associates the index with the corresponding letter

Maybe its more elegant using `enumerate`

`word_dict = {i: letter for i, letter in enumerate(word[:-1])}`

This yields the same result